# Extra unwanted octothorpe character in redirect URL

Tags: square-connect

The square-connect redirect seems to have an extra, unwanted, octothorpe (#) character in the redirect URL.

.../myservicepoint.com?#access_token=Eblah-blah-blah&token_type=bearer&merchant_id=secretID&response_type=token

This totally ruins the PHP capability to get the access token off of the URL $_REQUEST['#access_token']

Whats this there for?  The documentation does not mention this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out this gap in the documentation. If you specify `response_type=token` in your request to the [Authorize](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#get-authorize) endpoint, the query string of the request to your redirect URL is indeed escaped into a fragment with the `#` symbol. This is a security measure that prevents your application's access token from being logged.

There are two ways you can resolve your issue:

1. Parse the fragment string to extract your access token
2. Specify `response_type=code` instead of `response_type=token` in your request to the Authorize endpoint. This requires a followup request to the [Obtain Token](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#post-token) endpoint, but the query string provided to your redirect URL will *not* be escaped.

**Note**: Do not send requests to the Obtain Token endpoint from your application's client (e.g., a mobile app or webpage). The request requires your application secret, which should be stored and provided only by your application's back-end server.